# Terminology - are each of the eigenvectors of a PCA themselves called an "eigen portfolio"

Tags: pca, terminology, eigenvalue

Sorry, I suspect this is rather trivial but just want to confirm that, given a portfolio constructed of `n` assets, each of the `n` eigenvectors (assuming no cutoff / variance threshold etc. has been applied) produced as the result of a PCA of those asset's covariance are each themselves called "eigen portfolios"? i.e. one portfolio of n assets has become n eigen portfolios (of decreasing marginal explanatory power)? Thanks

Comment: Each eigenvector is an array of weights, so yes they're portfolios.

Comment: Do note that elements of eigen vectors do not sum to one, but their sum of squares equal one.

Comment: Maybe a separate question, but is it the elements of the eigen vector that are interpreted as weights or the loadings (those elements scaled by the square root of the eigen values)?